# Make colab use the latest installation of a library

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to use the bleeding edge version of sklearn installing it from their github as shown on line 2 in the below image. Line 5 imports some functions from this version of sklearn. This line works in my local and not on Google Colab. Am I missing something to hint the tool to use the latest installed version and not its cached version?

[image: Error snapshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why that's happening but if you uninstall scikit-learn before installing the latest dev, it would work:

```
[1] !pip uninstall scikit-learn -y
Uninstalling scikit-learn-0.19.1:
  Successfully uninstalled scikit-learn-0.19.1

[2]!pip install Cython
   !pip install git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (0.28.2)
Collecting git+git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git
  Cloning git://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-d59ukisw
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn==0.20.dev0) (1.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from scikit-learn==0.20.dev0) (0.19.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-learn
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scikit-learn ... done
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-is88dk15/wheels/a1/50/0e/316ef2ff8d4cfade292bd20b49efda94727688a153382745a6
Successfully built scikit-learn
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
Successfully installed scikit-learn-0.20.dev0

[3] !pip freeze | grep scikit
scikit-image==0.13.1
scikit-learn==0.20.dev0

[4] from sklearn.preprocessing import CategoricalEncoder

[5] import sklearn
    sklearn.__version__
'0.20.dev0'
```