# How to update scikit-learn in Google Colab?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I want to use `sklearn.metrics plot_confusion_matrix` in Google Colab. It comes with the latest stable update of sklearn 0.22.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py

I tried this [Make colab use the latest installation of a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379876/make-colab-use-the-latest-installation-of-a-library)

But in the end it shows the version of sklearn is still 0.21.

[image]

Comment: Did you try following the advice of the red text in your screenshot?

Comment: I tried to re-run it. But actually it has to be mannual restarted. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 6):

I uninstalled sklearn from colab like you do in the start of your image and reinstalled it again updating it as it is mentioned in sklearn documentation. The code I used was the following:

```
!pip uninstall scikit-learn -y

!pip install -U scikit-learn
```

After I checked if my version was updated with:

```
import sklearn

sklearn.__version__

'0.24.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to hit `Runtime > Restart Runtime`