# Is there a way to display and all dependencies and their versions in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Let's suppose i don't want to have the latest version automatically imported by colab notebook. I want to list all my dependencies, their versions and freeze the versions.
How can i list the versions?

Answer (score 3):

You can always use the `!` operator to run shell commands in colab (or jupyter notebooks). So if you do:

```
!pip freeze
```

you will be able to see the current versions of packages. To install a different version of package you can follow my answer here: [Make colab use the latest installation of a library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379876/make-colab-use-the-latest-installation-of-a-library/50386122#50386122)